# How to accept parameters (including images) through a json web service and store it into a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, json, wcf

I am getting an error:

> Operation 'addUser' in contract 'IService1' has a UriTemplate that expects a parameter named 'PHONE_NO,DP,REG_ID', but there is no input parameter with that name on the operation.

My code:

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
               UriTemplate = "addUser/{phone_no,dp,reg_id}")]
    void addUser(String phone_no, String dp, String reg_id);
}
```

and the `addUser` function is as follows:

```
 public void addUser(String phone_no, String dp, String reg_id)
 {
        string conn = "";
        conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ToString();

        SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
        objsqlconn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.User where phone_no in (" + phone_no + ")", objsqlconn);
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(ds);
        objsqlconn.Close();

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            objsqlconn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into dbo.User(phone_no,dp,reg_id) values(@phone_no,@dp,@reg_id)", objsqlconn);
            da.SelectCommand = cmd2;
            DataSet dt = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            objsqlconn.Close();
        }
   }
```

Here `dp` is the image can someone tell me if this is the right way to accept images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service can be something like this

```
[ServiceContract]
public class TestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/AddUser/{phoneNo}/{regId}")]
    public string AddUser(string phoneNo, String regId, Stream image)
    {
       //Read your stream here
       return phoneNo + " " + regId;
    }
}
```

You can invoke it as:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var stream = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(filename));
    var resp = await client.PostAsync("http://ip:port/TestService/AddUser/555111222/12345", stream);
    Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode.ToString());
}
```

Comment: where do I write this function?

Comment: @Sanjana I don't get you. One is server side code and the other one client side.