# HTTP 413 when POST image from Android to WCF Rest as stream

Tags: c#, android, wcf, rest, iis-7.5

I've tried a lot of tutorials with WCF reviving steaming data and still none works.

Let me tell you where is the problem.

I want to create rest service which accept image as stream parameter.

Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadFile", Method = "POST")]
string UploadFile(Stream fileContents);
```

Method:

```
public string FileUpload(string fileName, Stream fileStream)
{
     return "OK";
}
```

And main problem I think - web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="SimpleOcrService.OcrService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SimpleOcrService.IOcrService" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>    
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <verbs>
                    <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
                </verbs>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

From Android side I'm doing something like that:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.102:9009/OcrService.svc/UploadFile");  

FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(DATA_PATH+"/ocr.jpg"));
HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                                .addPart("myFile", bin)
                                .build();

postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

In resposne I always get "HTTP 413 (Entity Too Large)" :( Where is the problem?

Comment: Similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137314/how-to-accept-parameters-including-images-through-a-json-web-service-and-store

Comment: it's something different

Answer (score 0):

You need to change "uploadReadAheadSize" to make it bigger to accept your request. Below are steps to change uploadReadAheadSize.

1. Open iis manager.
2. Select the site where your service is hosted.
3. In the Features section, double click "Configuration Editor"
4. Under "Section" select: system.webServer > serverRuntime
5. Modify the value of "uploadReadAheadSize" to make it big enough to accept your request. Max is 2147483647.

Comment: So you think uploaded image size is greater than 2GB?

Comment: No. But uploadReadAheadSize setting on your server may be smaller than content length.

Comment: Thanks for the replay but it's not solved my problem. I have 214743647 in uploadReadAheadSize.